# Call controlgroup .click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, click

Trying to call the .click() method for a controlgroup in another method.  Heres what I have so far:

```
$("#list").click(function() {
    searchclick = true;
    value = $("#listval").text().split(" - ");
    window.location.href = "index.html";
    item = $("#listval").attr("title");
    if (item == "this") {
        $("#this").click();
    } else {
        $("#that").click();
    }
});​
```

"#this" and "#that" are the two buttons in the control group. The control group click method is initialized like so:

```
$("#this, #that").click(function(){ ...code... }
```

Any help?

EDIT: here is what the html looks like:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
            <div id="item" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>
                    </legend>
                    <input id="this" name="choose" value="val1" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="this">
                        val1
                    </label>
                    <input id="that" name="choose" value="val2" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="that">
                        val2
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            ...
```

Comment: is your problem that those click functions are never called?

Comment: Yes, I've tested with alerts in the if statements to make sure they are working, and they are.  The only problem is that the .click() methods are not firing.

Comment: using `window.location.href`, you are redirecting to some other page, so code below that line is never run.

Comment: Have you put alerts in the click handler to prove they're not being run?

Comment: @keune - put an alert after the window.location.href and it fired fine.  Also tried moving it until after and still nothing.  I have all methods for the index.html and this one (search.html) in the same .js file. So that they all share variables and should save states, correct? Barmar - I put an alert at the beginning of the method to see if it would fire (which it does not).

Comment: If you reload the page (by changing `location.href`) every Javascript variable is destroyed and lost for ever, and then recreated with it's initial state. It is possible that after changing `location.href` a few lines of code gets executed, but that isn't deterministic. Do you really need to refresh the page at that specific point?

Comment: No, I don't need it refreshed. Just thought it was the easiet way to change the page.  (I'm new to javascript/jquery) How would you suggest I change pages while keeping variables intact?  Note that I have to pass the value of the selected item in search to the index page in order to change certain items.

Comment: What do you have in server side? PHP, ASP, JSP, or it is plain HTML? two ways to do that are by submiting the form (for which you have to set the control's values server side) or by making a AJAX call and refreshing only the part of the HTML that you want to change.

Comment: I have just been using '$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'resources/file.xml',
   dataType: 'xml',
   success: function parseXML(xml){'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the variables to Local Variables and calling them in the `index.html` page.  In `index.html`, I used a try,catch block to check that when the page was loaded, if there are any variables in the Local Variables.  Here's my code in `index.html` (after list is clicked on the other page:

```
try{
//grab variables set in search
if(window.localStorage.getItem("searchclick") == "true"){
    searchclick = true; 
}else{searchclick = false}
thisthat = window.localStorage.getItem("thisthat");
if(thisthat == "this"){
    $("#this").click();
    $("#thislabel").addClass("ui-btn-hover-c");
    $("#thislabel").addClass("ui-radio-on");
    $("#thislabel").addClass("ui-btn-active");
}else if(thisthat == "that"){
    $("#that").click();
    $("#thatlabel").addClass("ui-btn-hover-c");
    $("#thatlabel").addClass("ui-radio-on");
    $("#thatlabel").addClass("ui-btn-active");
}
//clear local variables after being used
window.localStorage.clear();
```

}catch(err){alert(err);}

Answer (score 0):

This will send the current values to the server, where (I suppose) you have the code that will deal with the sent values and will generate the proper response.

**NOTES:**

- Are `searchclick` and `value` global variables? if so, they will be available inside the handlers of the *#this* and *#that*'s clicks, but will be lost after submitting the form.
- Is `item` a local variable? If so, you should declare it like this: `var item = $("#listval").attr("title");`. As a general rule: Don't create global variables unless is absolutely necessary.
- Next code may interfere with other code in your form. If fixing other code is too hard you may try the other option: instead of submitting the form, do a ajax call (see jQuery documentation for that [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

```
$("#list").click(function() {
    searchclick = true;
    value = $("#listval").text().split(" - ");
    item = $("#listval").attr("title");
    if (item == "this") {
        $("#this").click();
    } else {
        $("#that").click();
    }

    //your controls are inside a form, right?
    document.forms[0].submit();

});​
```

Comment: I am developing this for a mobile application. I plan on running this through PhoneGap.  Anyway, the method is going to use the #this and #that click method to call the appropriate xml data.  After this, a list will be generated with all of the object names in the xml file. Then according to that, the clicked value, value[0] will be the object it needs to select from that list. Then I will run the click method for that list and generate a second list.  value[1] will be the value that will be chosen in the second list, and upon using that list's click method I will display results.

Comment: /\ Just trying to show how the variables are only used in the method, so they do not really need to be transferred since this is all in the same .js file.  Note that I have not added the code for changing the lists and such just yet. Taking it one step at a time.